# Proving $S_3$ is not a coproduct of cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory

Aluffi II.6.11 suggests proving the above.

Here's the sketch of my proof by contradiction.

Assume that $S_3$ is a coproduct of a family $\mathcal{C}$ of cyclic groups $C^i$. Using the universal property for coproducts (and considering morphisms $\sigma_i : S_3 \rightarrow C^i$ such that $\sigma_i \iota_i = 1$, where $\iota_i$ is the injection function) shows that each $C^i$ cannot be larger (as a set) than $S_3$.

Next, since $S_3$ has three elements of order 2 and two elements of order 3, it can be shown that any cyclic group that maps its generator onto one of those elements shall have order 2 or 3 respectively.

So we're down to a corpoduct of a certain number of $C_2$ and $C_3$.

Now, by considering both elements of order 3 in $S_3$, it can be shown that having two $C_3 \in \mathcal{C}$ with different injection functions leads to contradiction, so we have at most one $C_3$. We also have to have at least one $C_2$ mapping onto some element of order 2, otherwise there's a certain freedom in defining the behavior of some morphisms from $S_3$. Similarly, we also have to have at least one $C_3$.

Now, considering the group $C_2 \times C_3$ along with a pair of morphisms $\varphi_2 : C_2 \rightarrow C_2 \times C_3, \varphi_2([n]_2) = ([n]_2, [0]_3)$ and $\varphi_3 : C_3 \rightarrow C_2 \times C_3, \varphi_3([n]_3) = ([0]_2, [n]_3)$ it can be shown that there is no valid homomorphism $\sigma : S_3 \rightarrow C_2 \times C_3$ satisfying the corresponding universal property for coproducts, hence the contradiction with the original assumption.

---

Overall, this looks quite clunky. Does it look reasonable though? Is there a better way to prove the claim (perhaps limited to the little amount of algebra and category theory that might be expected by this point)?

Comment: Isn't the free product (which is the coproduct of groups) of (nontrivial) cyclic groups infinite? If $C_1$ and $C_2$ are generated by $a$ and $b$, respectively, then can't I just make words like $ababababa$?

Comment: I recommend against using the term "proof by contradiction". You are proving a negative statement, i.e. "it is not the case that $S_3$ is a coproduct of cyclic groups". To prove a negative statement, you assume it and show that this leads to a contradiction. Proof by contradiction proves a *positive* statement by assuming its *negation* and showing that the negation leads to a contradiction. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/proof+by+contradiction briefly describes the difference, and I highly recommend Bauer's post referenced there.

Comment: "Proof by contradiction" is probably misused more often than it's used correctly, and this leads to its meaning being ambiguous. "Indirect proof" would be much less ambiguous when you are actually using proof by contradiction which you aren't in this case. You could say that you are doing a "proof of a negation", but you can probably just omit mention of proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem states

> “Since direct sums are coproducts in **Ab**, the classification theorem for abelian groups mentioned in the text says that every finitely generated *abelian group* is a coproduct of cyclic groups in **Ab**. The reader may be tempted to conjecture that every finitely generated *group* is a coproduct *in* **Grp**. Show this is not the case, by showing that $S_3$ is not a coproduct of cyclic groups.”

---

I think that your approach is a reasonable way of going about it given what information you have available. Certainly if $C_n$ is a factor of the coproduct then $n\in\{2,3\}$ as you mentioned, since these are the only nontrivial orders of elements in $S_3$.

I think the simplest way to move forward from here is to note that there should be a map $f:S_3\to C_3$ such that

$$C_3 \xrightarrow{i} S_3 \xrightarrow{f} C_3$$

is the identity map, if we assume that $S_3$ is a coproduct with a $i:C_3\to S_3$ factor. You can then reach a contradiction by showing that no such $f$ exists.

Comment: I don't think we have the machinery yet to show that a coproduct of groups in $\mathbf{Grp}$ is abelian (and it's not really that obvious to me, given that we don't know what a coproduct in $\mathbf{Grp}$ is at all).

Comment: @0xd34df00d Yeah, I agree. I edited my answer to reflect further thoughts I have. This question would be much easier (though perhaps not giving much practice with coproducts) if you knew that coproducts in **Grp** are free products (and are thus infinite nonabelian groups).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a maybe simpler proof, but which involves more concepts that may be unknown.

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$Suppose that a group $G$ is the coproduct of cyclic groups:
$$G = \Z/n_1\Z * \dots * \Z/n_k\Z.$$
Then the [abelianization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup#Abelianization) of $G$, i.e. its quotient by its commutator subgroup, is isomorphic to the direct sum $G_{\mathrm{ab}} \cong \Z/n_1\Z \oplus \dots \oplus \Z/n_k\Z$. So if we know the abelianization, we know what cyclic groups must be involved.

Now it's well-known that the commutator subgroup of $S_3$ is the alternating group $A_3$, and the quotient $(S_3)_{\mathrm{ab}}$ is the cyclic group $\Z/2\Z$. Therefore, if $S_3$ were a coproduct of cyclic groups, then it would be isomorphic to $\Z/2\Z$. This is obviously false because $S_3$ has $6$ elements whereas $\Z/2\Z$ only has two. Therefore $S_3$ cannot be isomorphic to a coproduct of cyclic groups.

Answer (score 1):

I have a much simpler way of contemplating this, but as a beginner, it might be flawed, so please let me know if it's not reasonable:

By the universal property of coproduct, there is a unique homomorphism from the direct sum of cyclic groups to S3. Now if we prove that the homomorphism has a inverse (i.e. that the homomorphism is actually a isomorphism), we are done.

To establish isomorphism, we need same number of elements (6), which constrains that C2*C3 the only possibility, because 2*3=6. Then, comparing the order of the 6 elements in both groups, we found out they are not isomorphic to each other.

This seems too simple a solution, so I doubt my thoughts here. Much appreciated for any comments.

Edit:
**This not the correct way to think, thanks to the comment.**

Comment: The direct sum is not the coproduct in the category of all groups.  It does not have the universal property you think it has. The coproduct in the category of groups is the free product.

Comment: Thanks, I see. Direct sum is the coproduct in the category of abelian groups though right?

Comment: @Yunhan, correct. It is a common mistake, though. You have two abelian groups $A$ and $B$ and you automatically think of their direct sum. The problem is that even though for any *abelian* group $C$, any pair of morphisms from the summands to $C$ factors through the direct sum. However, if $C$ is not abelian, then it is no longer true. The reason is that the direct sum contains relations that nonabelian $C$ won't permit in general, so you can't induce the morphism you want.